# Set the child class field value a different (from the parent) type value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In java and MongoDB, I have one parent-child who defining an Id as BigInteger and I want the child class to define it (and return it ) as objectId without changing the field definitions in the parent class.
I am trying something like this :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

Field fieldId = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("id");
fieldId.setAccessible(true); 
     
ObjectId convertedId = new ObjectId(this.id.toString(16));
fieldId.set(this, convertedId);
```

The `set()` method is not recognized as one of the reflect's.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?